# How to download the folders of installed extension from magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to download all the folders and files for my installed extension.
I think there is a url in Magento from where we can download the extension.
can anyone help please?

Comment: but you need to use extension key for direct download http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Comment: I have already installed the extension previouslly at that time the extension was free and now the extension is paid.
.Thats why i want to download the extension from my site.

Comment: I  got the answer.
This is the right path.
"[path to Magento]/downloader/.cache/community"

Comment: Please add it in your answer and also accept as correct answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. This is the right path. "[path to Magento]/downloader/.cache/community"